# Cannot override CSS Module class style with more specific one

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm having a problem applying a CSS Module to a React Component (in an app created with 'create-react-app' and using webpack).  I have an element that has a 'className' and an 'id' attribute.  The 'className' style get applied, but when I attempt to 'override' it with a more specific 'id' style, it doesn't take.  My Use Case is that the more-specific style override is in a separate file, but the problem exists with the two styles in the same CSS file.

Here's my component:

```
import React from 'react';
import styles from './styles.module.css'

class QuestionTag extends React.Component {

  render() {

    let c1 = "qumultiline";

    return (
      <>
        <div className={`${styles[c1]}`} id={`${c1}`}>      
          Hello there    
        </div>
      </>
    );    

  }

}

export default QuestionTag;
```

This is how the element gets rendered:

```
<div class="styles_qumultiline__iXUv1" id="qumultiline">Hello there</div>
```

Here's styles.module.css:

```
.qumultiline {
  background-color: #006699;
  color: white;
}

div#qumultiline {
  background-color: red;
  color: red;
}
```

Is there something special I need to do to be able to override the 'className'?

Comment: Should it be `id={`${c1}`}`? Or even just `id={c1}`?

Comment: your also using Material UI so shouldnt you use the `useStyles` hook?

Comment: @RichardHpaI simplified by removing material-ui

Comment: Is there a reason why you arent adding the ID the same way you are adding your class? ie you arent saying `id={`${styles[c1]}`} `

Comment: @RichardHpa because the value is 'id' is a string, not a style...?  Not sure assigning a style to a an 'id' makes any sense.